# Spacing problem with in-text citations - interaction between natbib and babel

Tags: citing, natbib, babel, languages, babel-greek

I just put my latex build on a new machine, and all the sudden I'm getting a problem with in-text citations: two-author citations don't have a space after the "&" in the in-text citation, even though the reference looks fine. It seems to be limited to files where I have Greek text, for which I'm using babel. An MWE is below. Any suggestions, including easy work-arounds, would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}


{\greektext >'estalka }\\

\cite{princesmolensky}, \cite{mp1995}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}

\bibitem[{McCarthy \& Prince(1995)}]{mp1995}
McCarthy, John~J. \& Alan Prince. 1995.
\newblock Faithfulness and {{Reduplicative Identity}}.
\newblock In Jill Beckman, Suzanne Urbanczyk \& Laura~Walsh Dickey (eds.),
  \emph{Papers in {{Optimality Theory}}} (University of {{Massachusetts
  Occasional Papers}} in {{Linguistics}}~18), 249--384. {Amherst, MA}:
  {Graduate Linguistics Student Association}.

\bibitem[{Prince \& Smolensky([1993] 2004)}]{princesmolensky}
Prince, Alan \& Paul Smolensky. [1993] 2004.
\newblock \emph{Optimality {{Theory}}: {{Constraint Interaction}} in
  {{Generative Grammar}}}.
\newblock {Malden, MA}: {Blackwell Publishing}.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions, including easy work-arounds, would be much appreciated.

I have two suggestions:

- Just change the `\bibitem` directives from

  ```
  \bibitem[{McCarthy \& Prince(1995)}]{mp1995}
  \bibitem[{Prince \& Smolensky([1993] 2004)}]{princesmolensky}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibitem[{McCarthy \&\ Prince(1995)}]{mp1995}
  \bibitem[{Prince \&\ Smolensky([1993] 2004)}]{princesmolensky}
  ```
- Alternatively, insert the following instructions toward the end of the preamble:

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  \apptocmd{\bbl@greek@ampersand}{\space}{}{}
  \makeatother
  ```

---

Now for a longer examination of what's going. If neither of the suggested fixes is applied, the aux file contains the following two lines of code if -- and, AFAICT, only if -- one of the `babel` language options is `polutonikogreek`:

```
\bibcite{mp1995}{{1}{1995}{{McCarthy \bbl@greek@ampersand   Prince}}{{}}}
\bibcite{princesmolensky}{{2}{[1993] 2004}{{Prince \bbl@greek@ampersand   Smolensky}}{{}}}
```

Observe that there are no spacing diretives after `\bbl@greek@ampersand`   . Yes, that's three [3] blank spaces at the end but, importantly, no `\`  spacing directive. It looks to me like a programming error may have snuck in. Either of the fixes suggested fixes serves to re-introduce the needed spacing after `\bbl@greek@ampersand`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\apptocmd' patching macro
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\bbl@greek@ampersand}{\space}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\greektext >'estalka}

\citet{princesmolensky}, \citep{mp1995}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}

\bibitem[McCarthy \& Prince(1995)]{mp1995}
McCarthy, John~J. \& Alan Prince. 1995.
\newblock Faithfulness and Reduplicative Identity.
\newblock In Jill Beckman, Suzanne Urbanczyk \& Laura~Walsh Dickey (eds.),
  \emph{Papers in Optimality Theory} (University of Massachusetts
  Occasional Papers in Linguistics~18), 249--384. Amherst, MA:
  Graduate Linguistics Student Association.

\bibitem[Prince \& Smolensky({[1993] 2004})]{princesmolensky}
Prince, Alan \& Paul Smolensky. [1993] 2004.
\newblock \emph{Optimality Theory: Constraint Interaction in
  Generative Grammar}.
\newblock Malden, MA: Blackwell Publishing.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used bibitems just to make the MWE easier, but I'm actually using BibTeX. When I re-compile the bbl file, the \ goes away. Other than waiting until the last time I compile to do this, can you think of any other ways to automate this fix? I've got a number of multi-author citations that this is going to apply to.

Comment: @SamZukoff  - Thanks for providing this clarification about how you use BibTeX. (I must confess that I was kind of scratching my head over what might be going on.) I've edited my answer to provided a second suggested fix. Please advise if if works for your setup (which I'm still not entirely sure I get...).

Comment: Yes, this did the trick!! Thank you so much.